# pythonでsalesforceから取得した2000件以上のデータをリストに格納したい

Tags: python

pythonもsalesforceも初心者です。
よろしくお願いします。

## やりたいこと

pythonからsalesforceにクエリを投げて取得したデータをリストに格納したい
最終的にはリストからcsv出力をしたい

## 困っていること

- クエリは成功している
- 取得したデータ（例えば3000件）をリストに格納すると2000件までで、残り1000件を格納できない
- 上限に引っかかっているのだろうと思うが、どうしたらいいか方法がわからない

## 環境

- Python 3.8.1
- simplesalesforceを使用

## コード

手探り状態のコードですがあげておきます

```
    q = a.sf.query("SELECT AccountCode__C, ID FROM Account Limit 3000")  
    cnt = q['totalSize']    
    with open(csv_dir, 'w', encoding='utf_8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n')
        val = [[x['AccountCode__c'],x['Id']] for x in q['records']]    
        for i in range(cnt):
            line = [val[i][0],val[i][1]]
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: [Simple Salesforce: Queries](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce#queries) に、'If, due to an especially large result, Salesforce adds a nextRecordsUrl to your query result, such as "nextRecordsUrl"' と書かれています。また、"As a convenience, to retrieve all of the results in a single local method call use `sf.query_all(...)`" とも書かれていますので、この `query_all()` メソッドを試してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: @metropolis  今日は環境から離れてしまっているので明日試してみます。

Answer (score 0):

助言いただいた通り、下記のように `query_all(...)`で全件取得できました。
`query_all(...)`は削除済みデータも含んでしまうので、削除済みを省きたい時は
オプションで`include_deleted=False`にしてあげると除外できました。

```
q = a.sf.query_all("SELECT AccountCode__C, ID FROM Account Limit 3000", include_deleted=False)
```